# Alternate view (hide/show)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components in my page, the first one is always displayed when we load the page and the second one is hidden. The second component must be displayed instead of the first one when the tab key is pressed so that we can alternate the view. Is there a way to do it in Angular2 ?
Here is my code.
This is the first component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-informations',
template: `
<div id="info">
              /*Informations here*/
              `
})
export class InformationsComponent {
}
```

Same thing for the second component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'chat-box',
template: `<div id="chatBox">
<p>{{title}}</p>
<div id="msg"> </div>
<textarea rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea>
</div>`
})
export class ChatBoxComponent {
    title = 'CHAT';
}
```

Comment: `*ngIf` . . . .

Comment: Are you asking how to handle the key press or how to hide elements?

Comment: Should I use the the template tag for both components ?

Comment: Use the variable in template.

Comment: @JimL yes how to handle the key press using the *ngIf

Comment: @RomanC which variable ?

Comment: keyPtess has no relation to `*ngIf` yoz also don't need a template tag. Just set a variable on keyPress and bind `*ngIf` to this variable.